# How to get a table populated with entries taken in from another screen of iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, custom-cell

I am making a app, in which i am taking the entries of the user from one screen and processing and printing them on another screen, these two screens are not consecutive screens. the problem is, the later screen dosen't get populated with the array of the details from the first
Here are the code files, that are connected for this input, processing and output

```
.......................pool.swift.......................

import UIKit
class Pool: NSObject
{
var name:String = ""
var route:String = ""
var date: String = ""
var capacity: Int = 4
var  car: String = ""
//var photo: UIImage
var email:String = ""

init(name:String, route:String, date: String, capacity: Int, car: String, email:String)
{
    self.name = name
    self.route = route
    self.date = date
    self.capacity = capacity
    self.car = car
    self.email = email
}
```

..............PoolManager.swift...........

```
import UIKit

class PoolManager: NSObject
{
static var pools = [Pool]()

class func AddPool(name:String, route:String, date: String, capacity: Int, car: String, email:String)
{
    let p = Pool(name: name, route:route, date:date, capacity: capacity, car:car, email:email)

    pools.append(p)
}

class func DeletePool(id: Int)
{
    pools.removeAtIndex(id)
}

class func GetPool() -> [Pool]
{
    return pools
}

}
```

.......UsePoolViewController.swift..............

```
import UIKit

class UsePoolViewController: UITableViewController
{

//let array = ["Ulhasnagar to Bandra", "Thane to Ghatkopar", "Kalyan to Thane", "Thane to Colaba"]

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return PoolManager.pools.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell")! as! customcell

        let pooler = PoolManager.pools[indexPath.item]

        cell.cellbox?.route = pooler.route
        // this statement doesnt work properly, cellbox gets a nil value.

        return cell

    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "PoolingDetails"
    {
        let cell = sender as! customcell

        let PoolingDetails = segue.destinationViewController as! UsePoolDetailsViewController

        PoolingDetails.heading = cell.cellbox?.route




    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

..........UsePoolDetailsViewController.swift........

```
  import UIKit

class UsePoolDetailsViewController: UIViewController
{
var heading:String?

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    self.title = heading
}
}
```

....customcell.swift......

```
import UIKit

class customcell: UITableViewCell
{
var cellbox:Pool?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st option: You can create a SharedClass which will have the data which you need throughout the app. In your case you need to update the sharedData regularly to access updated data on other screens of the applications.

2nd option: You can use the NSUserDefaults to keep the data which you can use throughout the application.

Comment: I am completely new to swift and iOS, Please can you guide me a bit more?
and why isnt the my code working? any Idea?

Comment: Using NSUserDefaults for this would be a bad idea, NSUserDefaults isn't designed to be used for holding global state, it's for storing user preferences. From the  [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/),

"The defaults system allows an application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences."

Comment: @AlexChesters you are correct.But we can use it for temporary purpose and can remove the data from it once we are done with using that data.

Comment: @Harshavardhan I think even that would be a great misuse of NSUserDefaults, I'd suggest your first option as by far the better approach.

Comment: @AlexChesters yes you are correct, and yes the 1st option is the best in this case, as per my understanding.